# How to implement the missing at random (MAR) assumption in mixed model using SAS proc mixed?

Tags: sas, mixed-models

Here is example data for repeated measure clinical trail study wehre `ResVal` is the response variable and there are two treatment arm. Data are collected in five timepoints.
`

```
data draft;
input subID baseline ResVal visits$ treat$ trtN;
datalines;
1 10 15 1 Active 1
1 10 20 2 Active 1
1 10 15 3 Active 1
1 10 25 4 Active 1
1 10 18 5 Active 1
2 12 14 1 Active 1
2 12 18 2 Active 1
2 12 20 3 Active 1
2 12 10 4 Active 1
2 12 15 5 Active 1
3 15 15 1 Placebo 0
3 15 20 2 Placebo 0
3 15 15 3 Placebo 0
3 15 25 4 Placebo 0
3 15 15 5 Placebo 0
4 10 14 1 Placebo 0
4 10 18 2 Placebo 0
4 10 20 3 Placebo 0
4 10 10 4 Placebo 0
4 10 20 5 Placebo 0
;
run;
```

`

here is the code for mixed model

``

```
proc mixed data=draft;
class treat visits;
model ResVal= treat baseline visits treat*visits;
repeated visits/subject=subID type=CS; 
lsmeans treat*visits/cl diffs ;
run;
```

``

How can I implement the MAR assumption in this code?

Comment: A short explanation of MAR and/or a link would be of value here.